# Fermat's numbers as the difference of two consecutive squares

Tags: number-theory

By well known result we know that Fermat's number is prime if and only if it can be uniquely written in the sum of two squares.
My question is that: Can we write every Fermat's number as the difference of two consecutive squares.
Using that I want to relate the problem with Legendre's conjecture that is there exist a prime between any two consecutive squares.

Comment: Ok, let there exist a prime between any two consecutive squares. And how it connects with Fermat's numbers?

Comment: Every odd number ($> 1$ if you disallow $0^2$) can be written as the difference of two consecutive squares.

Comment: @ michael: oh difference wont help me in that case & even Legendre would be quite away to relate in that case. Thank you sir for nice query.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Every odd number is a difference of consecutive squares - we have $2k+1=(k+1)^2-k^2$.